# Which object the function nth access to when applied to functional argument in Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have some problem using accessor function **nth**. I pass a list to some function and make new binding to an element of the list in the function with **nth**, then when I call the list out of the function, it is modified, and it's not what I want! What happens?

Some examples

```
(defun test (x) (incf x)) => TEST
(setq a 1) => 1
(test a) => 2
a => 1
```

I understand what's going on above, but if we change everything to lists, something happens that I can't understand

```
(defun test (x) (incf (nth 0 x))) => TEST
(setq a '(1)) => (1)
(test a) => 2
a => (2)
```

I expected a to be (1), why it has been modified? I also tried other functions like **car** and **first**, result is the same.

PS, I tried it in Lispworks and SBCL, same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun test (x) (incf x)) => TEST
(setq a 1) => 1
(test a) => 2
a => 1
```

You pass `1` to `test`. Within test you modified the local variable `x`. `a` is not changed and can't be changed that way - we pass the value of `a` not a reference to `a`.

```
(defun test (x) (incf (nth 0 x))) => TEST
(setq a '(1)) => (1)
(test a) => 2
a => (2)
```

You pass the list `(1)` to test. The list is not copied. The local variable `x` points to the first cons cell in the list. You then modify the *car* of the first cons cell to 2. Since the list is not copied, you modify the passed list. `a` also points to the first cons cell of that list. So it is also `(2)`.

Comment: Thank you! That's not really functional way of dealing with lists... If I want to make everything "functional", I have to form a new list like `(list (1+ (nth 0 x)))` (not particularly correct, but the idea is clear), am I correct?

Comment: @TheEnt: Common Lisp never copies data structures like lists, arrays, streams, conditions, CLOS objects, structures. Most Lisps don't do that.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want anything to be modified, don't use `incf`. Use `1+`. The only reason to use `incf` is because you want its side-effect.

As to why this is happening, arguments are evaluated before being passed to a function. When you call `test` with `a` being 1, you are passing the value 1, which cannot be modified. When `a` resolves to a list, you are passing a list, which can be `setf`'d all over the shop, if you've chosen to use destructive functions.

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation on [nth](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm).  `nth` returns a place that `setq` can then operate on.

> nth may be used to specify a place to setf. Specifically,
>   (setf (nth n list) new-object) ==  (setf (car (nthcdr n list)) new-object)

Comment: Thanks, I've alreay read this. It seems I've found the reason - lists are passed by reference in CL, so that's why the original list is modified.

Comment: No, lists are not passed by reference.  They are passed by value like everything else.  It is just that the value of a list happens to _be_ a reference.  That is a big difference.